# inserting xml documents in orientdb

Tags: orientdb

I have just started OrientDB and did the tutorials but there is one piece of functionality that I can't seem to find.
I have a collection of XML documents (on disk) that I want to import as Vertexes in the database for then doing queries .
Those documents have relationship to sessions that are essentially edges and that I will add later after the import.
Is it easy to import XML files then or I should use another DB?
Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no out of the box support for storing native XML documents (other than storing it as a CLOB). If OrientDB is a good fit for your use case or not is highly dependent on your specific data model. If your XML documents have a simple structure and can be mapped without information loss (and back) to JSON this may be a good fit. Also, how important is the Graph support for you? 
Otherwise I highly recommend [eXist-db](http://exist-db.org/) as XML database. It is also Java based, open source and has a active community.

Comment: Yes this is actually what I was looking for! The graph part is not relevant for my task as I just have to be able to query all files to extract specific tags conditionally or unconditionally. Thanks this is awesome!